# Irreducible module

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I've met the following definition of irreducible module: an $R$ module $M$ is said to be *irreducible* if it contains no proper submodules: in other words, if $N \subset M$ is a submodule than either $n=0$ or $N=M$. Form the other side, one can think of module map $R \times M \to M$ as a representation $\pi\colon R \to \operatorname{End}(M)$ (where $M$ is viewed as an abelian group) via the formula $\pi(r)m:=rm$. Suppose that $R$ and $M$ are also vector spaces (over $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$). My question is the following: does the notion of irreducibility coincide with the following property: a representation $\pi$ is irreducible? The latter would mean that the only module maps $T:M \to M$ are of the form $cI_{M}$ where $c \in \mathbb{K}$

Comment: Your second definition of irreducibility is rather unorthodox.

Comment: I would not call the second property a 'definition'-it was my first quess what does the notion of irreducibility could mean: I've checked the definition, found the different one (different from my guess) and wondered whether these notion are equivalent :). However, I'd prefer to call such module "simple".

Comment: Simple is universally defined to meanyour first concept, that there are no proper submodules. A module whose endomorphisms are scalar multiples of the identity is often called a *brick*.

Comment: If $R$ is commutative then certainly there are $R$-linear multiples of the identity that act as $R$-module endomorphisms of $M$, but $R$ can be strictly bigger than the smaller field of scalars $K$.

Answer (score 2):

The two things are not equivalent. There are modules which are irreducible in the first sense and not in the second.

For example, let R be a division ring and M=R. As soon as R contains your field strictly, there are non-scalar endomorphisms.

Comment: Thank You, so in particular You could take $\mathbb{C}$ as a $\mathbb{C}$ module but viewed as $\mathbb{R}$ vector space and take endomorphism $z \mapsto wz$ where $w$ is not a real number. Are You able to do such a construction in case $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$ and $R$-commutative?

Comment: Take R=C(t), the field o rational functions in the variable t.